# Proving that $P\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^n E_j^{(n)}\right)\sim\sum_{j=1}^n P(E_j^{(n)})$ for independent events $E_j^{(n)}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> For arbitrary events $\{E_j, 1\le j\le n\}$, we have
>
> $$P\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^n E_j\right)\ge\sum_{j=1}^n P(E_j) - \sum_{1\le j < k \le n} P(E_jE_k)$$
>
> If $\forall n: \{E_j^{(n)}, 1\le j\le n \}$ are independent events, and
>
> $$P\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^n E_j^{(n)} \right)\to 0 \quad \text{as} \quad n\to\infty$$
>
> then $P\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^n E_j^{(n)} \right) \sim \sum_{j=1}^n P(E_j^{(n)})$.

*My attempt at showing this last claim:*

I am going to guess that the ~ symbol in the problem means that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{P\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^n E_j^{(n)} \right)}{\sum_{j=1}^n P(E_j^{(n)})}=1$$

From

$$\sum_{j=1}^n P(E_j^{(n)})\ge P\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^n E_j^{(n)}\right)\ge\sum_{j=1}^n P(E_j^{(n)}) - \sum_{1\le j < k \le n} P(E_j^{(n)}E_k^{(n)})$$

and dividing we have

$$1\ge \frac{P\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^n E_j^{(n)}\right)}{\sum_{j=1}^n P(E_j^{(n)})} \ge 1 - \frac{\sum_{1\le j < k \le n} P(E_j^{(n)}E_k^{(n)})}{\sum_{j=1}^n P(E_j^{(n)})}$$

so then the problem reduces to showing

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{1\le j < k \le n} P(E_j^{(n)}E_k^{(n)})}{\sum_{j=1}^n P(E_j^{(n)})} = 0$$

But how to make progress after that?

Comment: I have tried to make the distinction between the "problem statement" and your attempted solution clearer. I'm not sure how the first line and displayed equation contribute to the question, though. Could you either make that clear, or remove it (because it is the first thing readers see, and if it's not concerning the problem that may confuse them)?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $$\sum_{1\leqslant j<k\leqslant n}\mu(E_jE_k)=\sum_{1\leqslant j<k\leqslant n}\mu(E_j)\mu(E_k)=\frac 12\left(\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\mu(E_j)\right)^2-\sum_{j=1}^n\mu(E_j)^2\right).$$
Dividing by $\sum \mu(E_j)$, the first term is not problematic. For the second one, write 
$$\sum_{j=1}^n\mu(E_j)^2\leqslant \max_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}\mu(E_k)\cdot \sum_{j=1}^n\mu(E_j)\leqslant \mu\left(\bigcup_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}E_k\right)\cdot \sum_{j=1}^n\mu(E_j).$$

Comment: The resulting expressions still involve $\sum_{j=1}^n \mu(E_j)$. How does one control such terms showing that they are small?

Comment: Once you divide by this sum, we get something which converges to $0$ by assumption.

Comment: How does the assumption that $\mu(\cup E_j)$ converges to 0 give that $\sum \mu(E_j)$ converges to 0?

Comment: It's not what I said (I said that $\frac{\sum \mu(E_j)^2}{\sum\mu(E_j)}\leq \mu(\bigcup E_j)$.

Comment: So then $\frac{\sum_{1\le j< k\le n}\mu(E_jE_k)}{\sum\mu(E_j)}= \frac{1}{2}\left( \sum\mu(E_j) - \frac{\sum\mu(E_j)^2}{\sum\mu(E_j)} \right)$ is suppose to converge to $0$. How does that inequality show that?

Comment: The term $\sum\mu(E_j)$ goes to $0$ by assumption. And I proved that the second term is smaller or equal to $\mu\bigcup E_j^n$, and this measure converges to $0$ (because it is smaller than the sum of measures).

Comment: The assumption says $\mu(\cup E_j)$ goes to $0$ but doesn't explicitly mention $\sum\mu(E_j)$

Comment: Ops, sorry. So forget the last (useless) bound I gave you.

Answer (score 0):

A quantitative version of the result, proved by a recursion over the number of events involved: for every independent events $E_i$,
$$
1-P\left(E\right)\leqslant\frac{P\left(E\right)}{\sum\limits_iP(E_i)}\leqslant1,\qquad E=\bigcup\limits_iE_i.
$$
Thus, for independent events $E_i^{(n)}$, the events $E^{(n)}=\bigcup\limits_iE_i^{(n)}$ are such that
$$
P\left(E^{(n)}\right)\to0\implies P\left(E^{(n)}\right)\sim\sum\limits_iP(E_i^{(n)}).
$$